# C# 8.0 switch expression based on input type

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Is it possible to create `switch expression` in C# 8 based on input type?

My input classes looks like this:

```
public class A1
{
    public string Id1 {get;set}
}

public class A2 : A1
{
    public string Id2 {get;set}
}

public class A3 : A1
{
    public string Id3 {get;set;}
}
```

I want to run diffrent methods based on input type (`A1`, `A2`, or `A3`):

```
var inputType = input.GetType();
var result = inputType switch
{
       inputType as A1 => RunMethod1(input); // wont compile, 
       inputType as A2 => RunMethod2(input); // just showing idea
       inputType as A3 => RunMethod3(input);

}
```

But it wont work. Any ideas how to create switch or switch expression based on input type?C

Comment: Try starting the switch with most specific type first (A3) and work your way down to least specific (A1)

Comment: But my code wont compile, i just showed idea

Comment: Oh yeah I see it now, replace as with is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pattern matching, checking for the most specific types first.

`GetType` is unneccesary:

```
var result = input switch
{
    A2 _ => RunMethod1(input),
    A3 _ => RunMethod2(input),
    A1 _ => RunMethod3(input)    
};
```

However, a more OO approach would be to define a method on the types themselves:

```
public class A1
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public virtual void Run() { }
}

public class A2 : A1
{
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
    public override void Run() { }
}
```

Then it's simply:

```
input.Run();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but your code wont compile. Im getting this error: `The Pattern has already been handled by previous arm of switch expression`

Comment: @michasaucer It compiles fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1dGHUz

Comment: Your answer compiles for me too... So now i need figuring out why it wont in my scenerio (i just pasted base example here in SO). Thanks!

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay if you change the instance to `A2` or `A3` [it wont compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H4w59Y) see the second point of "notes" in my answer.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, I probably should have explicitly typed the variable in my fiddle.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i didnt mark your post as answer because Jamiec was faster but still you deserve for upvote

Comment: @michasaucer Not to be pedantic, but I answered first ;)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay sure, my bad, i edited, thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You can, but in an inheritance hierarchy like that you need to start with the most specific and move down towards the least:

```
A1 inputType = new A2();
var result = inputType switch
{
    A3 a3 => RunMethod(a3),
    A2 a2 => RunMethod(a2),
    A1 a1 => RunMethod(a1)
};
```

Note that

- `inputType` is an instance, not an instance of `Type`
- `inputType` is typed as the base class but can be an instance of any A1-3. Otherwise you'll get a compiler error.

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ip2BNZ